# unable to find /home/user

Tags: boot, startup

I am not able to boot Ubuntu. I am facing four problems in serial and I am stating each one below:

1) When I switch on my computer the Ubuntu boots than at starting it says:

```
the disk drive for /boot/uboot is not ready yet or not present
wait or press S to skip or M to add manually.
```

2) After pressing **S** then I go to login, then after login using my password, my home screen pops a message:

```
could not update ICEauthority file. /home/
user/.ICEauthority
```

3) Then I press enter, then again an error message pops saying:

```
There is a problem with the configuration server. (/usr/lib/libgconf
2-4/ifconf-sanity-check
-2 exited with status 256)
```

4) Then after pressing Enter, I get another error message

```
Nautilus could not create the following required
folders:/home/user/Desktop, /home/user/.nautilus
```

These are the four problems that I am getting. Please do help me. I also saw some solutions on the Net and tried them but I am not able to solve them so thought that
it is better to ask at this forum, waiting for your valuable response.

The solutions that I tried so far from the text console with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>:

```
sudo chmod 755/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.system
mkdir -p /etc/gconf/gconf.xml.system
chmod 755 /etc/gconf/gconf.xml.system
su root 
chmod 777 /tmp
chmod 777 /tmp/*
reboot
```

What's wrong with my system?

Comment: Please post the output of the following commands after you have started your text console: `ls -l /home`, `mount`, `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda`. It might be helpful to know more about what procedure you followed to create your Ubuntu system.

Comment: for ls -l /home the output is total 0.
for sudo gdisk -l the output is gdisk command not found.
for mount the output is 

/dev/sda on / type ext4
none on /proc type
none on /sys type
none on /sys/kernel/debug type
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connection type
none on /sys/kernel/debug type
none on /sys/kernel/security type
none on /dev type
none on /dev/pts type
none on /dev/shm type
none on /var/run type
none on /var/lock type
none on /lib/init/rw type

/scratchbox on /scratchbox/user/megharaj/scarchbox type name
same for tmp,proc,dev,dev/pts, dev/shm,sys

Comment: It appears that your system's /home directory tree is missing. Either it got erased; or if this is a brand new install, the install went bad; or you set up your system to have a separate partition for /home and something happened to that partition or it can no longer be found for some reason. If you want to pursue it further I suggest that you ask the question "What happened to my /home directory", give details about how you set it up and what its history is, and if you might have set up a separate /home partition, include the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda` and contents of /etc/fstab.

Comment: @john thanks for the replay.. the problem was " you set up your system to have a separate partition for /home and something happened to that partition or it can no longer be found for some reason" you are right